# Phpmailer not working running from localhost (XAMPP)

Tags: xampp, phpmailer

I am being troubled from the send mail function using phpmailer running at localhost.

I use `XAMPP, phpmailer`

The  `$mail->IsSMTP()` or `$mail->IsSendmail()` is working well on the hosting, but not localhost.

I had tried many solution mentioned on the internet, such as enabled the `OPENSSL (extension=php_openssl.dll)`

```
For using $mail->IsSendmail() of phpmailer, it shown "Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail".

For using $mail->IsSMTP() with well configured, all are setting correctly.
```

It shows

```
 "SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.",
```

I had the info from its debugger, there is info `"...SMTP -> ERROR: Password not accepted from server:..."`

But those had no problem on the live hosting environment, just only not work at localhost.

Hope someone can give me some idea. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`isSendmail` is unlikely to work on Windows - use `isMail` if you have a local mail server installed, and if you do, make sure it's up and running (e.g. `telnet localhost 25`). `isSMTP` sends directly and is unaffected by local mail config, which is why it's working for you. You should also [read the troubleshooting docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Answer (score -2):

Download & INSTALL  PHPMailer

> https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
>   Extract *class.phpmailer.php* and *class.smtp.php*
>   uncomment *;extension=php_openssl.dll* in *php.ini* normaly located under **xampp/php/** folder
>   find **[mail function]** and change (for Microsoft)

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
sendmail_from = yrmailaddress@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

Edit *class.smtp.php*, host and port parameters like (for Linux):  **$host="ssl://smtp.gmail.com" $port=465**

[edit delete sendmail params]

Example code for sending mail:

```
   <?php
require_once "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "yourusername@gmail.com"; // Enter your SMTP username
$mail->Password = "yourpassword“; // SMTP password
$webmaster_email = "yourusername@yourdoamin.com"; //Add reply-to email address
$email="yourusername@domain.com"; // Add recipients email address
$name="name"; // Add Your Recipient’s name
$mail->From = $webmaster_email;
$mail->FromName = "Webmaster";
$mail->AddAddress($email,$name);
$mail->AddReplyTo($webmaster_email,"Webmaster");
$mail->WordWrap = <strong>50</strong>; // set word wrap
$mail->AddAttachment("/var/tmp/file.tar.gz"); // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("/tmp/image.jpg", "new.jpg"); // attachment
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

$mail->Subject = "This is your subject";

$mail->Body =      "Hi, this is your email body, etc, etc" ;      //HTML Body

$mail->AltBody = "Hi, this is your email body, etc, etc";     //Plain Text Body
if(!$mail->Send()){
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message has been sent";
}
?>
```

Comment: Lots of bad advice here I'm afraid. PHPMailer has not been maintained on google code for a long time - [get it from github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). The (obsolete) example code has been corrupted with culy quotes. The gmail settings are not correct. sendmail.ini settings are irrelevant because you're using direct SMTP.

Comment: I answered too quickly, I had not corrected the parameters googles or quotes in the code and I forgot a paragraph on sendmail I finally removed because I agree it's not really useful .
to want to go too fast I forget to correct my mistakes, sorry --".